# How do I load html content in when using onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, buttonclick

I am working on a small random project of mine but I have run into a problem. I am using onclick button event to organise pictures with different themes. However, when I try to put code into the .innerHTML part it breaks the code and it won't work. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Function1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img>imagelinkgoeshere</img>"
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button style="width:100px;font-size:20px;font-family:Playball;color:#910000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);border:solid 0px #fff" onclick="Function1()">Theme1</button>

<p id="demo">Photos appear here</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, there'd be more buttons and therefore more themes but I am just showing you the basics to keep it uncluttered. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need another Javascript code or output to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks and it won't work"? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your image HTML is wrong. The syntax for an image is

```
<img src="imagelinkgoeshere">
```

So the function should be:

```
function Function1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<img src="imagelinkgoeshere">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps better alternative to using `innerHTML` is to dynamically create the image HTML element and then insert it in the div:

```
function Function(1) {
    var container = document.getElementById('demo');
    var img = document.createElement('img'); // creates an <img> HTML element
    img.src = 'imageurl.png'; // Giving the image some a target to display
    demo.appendChild(img); // Add the newly created image to the container #demo

}
```